# Procedural fairness letter response

Tags: canada

I have received a PFL from Canada embassy stating that i used compensate representative for submitting my application.

Actually i didn't, but i can understand the concerns of the officer because i also submitted an application for my friend days after i submitted mine, now i have all evidence for the friendship relationship.

What i need to understand is how to prove both applications come from me?

Comment: are you able to post a scan of the letter with your name and other sensitive information blocked out? You get a letter like this because they are about to deny you, but want to give you a chance (fairness) to respond to their concerns.

Comment: Using a paid agent in an application is not a crime or a reason to reject you. They will have other concerns that the letter will tell you about. If they also received other applications with very similar wording that could be a problem. The [official advice about PFLs](https://www.canadaimmigrationvisa.ca/procedural-fairness-letter) says you may want to take legal advice. If you do get it from a licensed immigration consultant.